# AngularJS - changing classes of elements based on their size and size of parrent element

Tags: angularjs

I'm placing "boxes" next to each other but they don't have same width.
What I want to do is to place "clearfix" after a "last box in the row", so if there is no space for another box, it will push it to next line.

I'm displaying boxes using `ng-repeat`
How can I get width of each element and width of parrent element ?

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a bad idea. You should be able to target last element with CSS and not JS.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna How could I target the last element using css if they don't have the same width?

Answer (score 0):

That must be handled by CSS. Can you paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use either the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) or [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) selector. Both will target the last matching element in the source, so your question of how to target the last element if "they don't have the same width" isn't an issue. It goes by source order.

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger that by doing the following

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{clearfix:$last}"></div>
```

Doing so the last element of the list will have the class **clearfix**, but it's not a good idea to do it in JavaScript, you better use plain CSS.